# Access request from inherit class ( view )

Tags: python, django, inheritance, request

How can I acces the var request if I not implement the methods get/post from a inherit class( view ) ?

```
class Base(View): 
    def __init__(self):
          self.menu="options": [
            {
                "link": "home:IndexHome",
                "name": "Base",
                "class": "icon-dashboard",
                "section" : "home",

            },
            {
                "link": "reports:IndexReports",
                "name": "Informes",
                "class": "icon-list-alt",
                "section":"reports",
            }]}
   def somemethod(self):
           request.session['idsession']
```

And what happens if some view inherit from Base? Like this.

```
class login(Base):

def __init__(self):
    Base.__init__(self)
```

The error is : 'login' object has no attribute 'request'

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`request` object is available as a property of a `View` instance:

```
def somemethod(self):
    self.request.session['idsession']
```

Comment: Sorry, I should say and what happens if some view inherite from Base ? ( I edited my post )

Comment: You want to access `request` in the `__init__` constructor?  It is impossible - there is no requests at this time. `request` attribute is set later in the `dispatch()` method - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch

Comment: Okey thanks a lot, and the last question.... How can I call a method in Base for each inherit class?( need the request )  Thx again and happy holidays.

Comment: `dispatch()` is called for every request so it is a good place to put some mandatory logic for descendant Views.